# Flutter Engine fails to compile, FAILED: clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/vm_snapshot_data.bin

Tags: c++, flutter, compiler-errors

When I try to compile Flutter in my environment(macOS、M1), I get the following error.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

```
~/development/engine/src# ninja -C out/host_debug_unopt
ninja: Entering directory `out/host_debug_unopt'
[4610/5246] ACTION //third_party/dart/runtime/bin:generate_snapshot_bin(//build/toolchain/mac:clang_arm64)
FAILED: clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/vm_snapshot_data.bin clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/vm_snapshot_instructions.bin clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/isolate_snapshot_data.bin clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/isolate_snapshot_instructions.bin
python3 ../../third_party/dart/build/gn_run_binary.py compiled_action clang_arm64/gen_snapshot --sound-null-safety --deterministic --snapshot_kind=core --vm_snapshot_data=clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/vm_snapshot_data.bin --vm_snapshot_instructions=clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/vm_snapshot_instructions.bin --isolate_snapshot_data=clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/isolate_snapshot_data.bin --isolate_snapshot_instructions=clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/isolate_snapshot_instructions.bin /Users/rentoezoe/development/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/clang_arm64/vm_platform_strong_stripped.dill
Command failed: ./clang_arm64/gen_snapshot --sound-null-safety --deterministic --snapshot_kind=core --vm_snapshot_data=clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/vm_snapshot_data.bin --vm_snapshot_instructions=clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/vm_snapshot_instructions.bin --isolate_snapshot_data=clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/isolate_snapshot_data.bin --isolate_snapshot_instructions=clang_arm64/gen/third_party/dart/runtime/bin/isolate_snapshot_instructions.bin /Users/rentoezoe/development/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/clang_arm64/vm_platform_strong_stripped.dill
output: ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/cpuinfo_macos.cc: 42: error: unreachable code
version=2.15.0-110.0.dev (dev) (Wed Sep 15 09:12:52 2021 -0700) on "macos_x64"
pid=55356, thread=259, isolate_group=(nil)(0x0), isolate=(nil)(0x0)
isolate_instructions=0, vm_instructions=0
  pc 0x000000010088fe00 fp 0x000000016f835de0 dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace(void*)+0x90
  pc 0x00000001005fa974 fp 0x000000016f835e00 dart::Assert::Fail(char const*, ...) const+0x28
  pc 0x00000001007522d8 fp 0x000000016f836240 dart::CpuInfo::FieldContains(dart::CpuInfoIndices, char const*)+0xb0
  pc 0x000000010075201c fp 0x000000016f836260 dart::HostCPUFeatures::Init()+0x64
  pc 0x00000001007526f4 fp 0x000000016f836480 dart::Dart::DartInit(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, _Dart_Isolate* (*)(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, Dart_IsolateFlags*, void*, char**), bool (*)(void**, char**), void (*)(void*, void*), void (*)(void*, void*), void (*)(void*), void (*)(), void* (*)(char const*, bool), void (*)(unsigned char**, long*, void*), void (*)(void const*, long, void*), void (*)(void*), bool (*)(unsigned char*, long), _Dart_Handle* (*)(), bool, Dart_CodeObserver*)+0x2e0
  pc 0x0000000100752c94 fp 0x000000016f836500 dart::Dart::Init(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, _Dart_Isolate* (*)(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, Dart_IsolateFlags*, void*, char**), bool (*)(void**, char**), void (*)(void*, void*), void (*)(void*, void*), void (*)(void*), void (*)(), void* (*)(char const*, bool), void (*)(unsigned char**, long*, void*), void (*)(void const*, long, void*), void (*)(void*), bool (*)(unsigned char*, long), _Dart_Handle* (*)(), bool, Dart_CodeObserver*)+0x74
  pc 0x0000000100fbcf0c fp 0x000000016f836560 Dart_Initialize+0x68
  pc 0x00000001005cd600 fp 0x000000016f836700 dart::bin::main(int, char**)+0x650
  pc 0x00000001a0b21430 fp 0x000000016f836720 start+0x4
-- End of DumpStackTrace

[4611/5246] ACTION //flutter/lib/snapshot:generate_snapshot_bin(//build/toolchain/mac:clang_x64)
FAILED: gen/flutter/lib/snapshot/vm_isolate_snapshot.bin gen/flutter/lib/snapshot/vm_snapshot_instructions.bin gen/flutter/lib/snapshot/isolate_snapshot.bin gen/flutter/lib/snapshot/isolate_snapshot_instructions.bin
python3 ../../build/gn_run_binary.py clang_arm64/gen_snapshot --snapshot_kind=core --enable_mirrors=false --vm_snapshot_data=/Users/rentoezoe/development/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/gen/flutter/lib/snapshot/vm_isolate_snapshot.bin --vm_snapshot_instructions=/Users/rentoezoe/development/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/gen/flutter/lib/snapshot/vm_snapshot_instructions.bin --isolate_snapshot_data=/Users/rentoezoe/development/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/gen/flutter/lib/snapshot/isolate_snapshot.bin --isolate_snapshot_instructions=/Users/rentoezoe/development/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/gen/flutter/lib/snapshot/isolate_snapshot_instructions.bin --enable_asserts /Users/rentoezoe/development/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/flutter_patched_sdk/platform_strong.dill
../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/cpuinfo_macos.cc: 42: error: unreachable code
version=2.15.0-110.0.dev (dev) (Wed Sep 15 09:12:52 2021 -0700) on "macos_x64"
pid=55354, thread=259, isolate_group=(nil)(0x0), isolate=(nil)(0x0)
isolate_instructions=0, vm_instructions=0
  pc 0x000000010494be00 fp 0x000000016b779d40 dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace(void*)+0x90
  pc 0x00000001046b6974 fp 0x000000016b779d60 dart::Assert::Fail(char const*, ...) const+0x28
  pc 0x000000010480e2d8 fp 0x000000016b77a1a0 dart::CpuInfo::FieldContains(dart::CpuInfoIndices, char const*)+0xb0
  pc 0x000000010480e01c fp 0x000000016b77a1c0 dart::HostCPUFeatures::Init()+0x64
  pc 0x000000010480e6f4 fp 0x000000016b77a3e0 dart::Dart::DartInit(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, _Dart_Isolate* (*)(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, Dart_IsolateFlags*, void*, char**), bool (*)(void**, char**), void (*)(void*, void*), void (*)(void*, void*), void (*)(void*), void (*)(), void* (*)(char const*, bool), void (*)(unsigned char**, long*, void*), void (*)(void const*, long, void*), void (*)(void*), bool (*)(unsigned char*, long), _Dart_Handle* (*)(), bool, Dart_CodeObserver*)+0x2e0
  pc 0x000000010480ec94 fp 0x000000016b77a460 dart::Dart::Init(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, _Dart_Isolate* (*)(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, Dart_IsolateFlags*, void*, char**), bool (*)(void**, char**), void (*)(void*, void*), void (*)(void*, void*), void (*)(void*), void (*)(), void* (*)(char const*, bool), void (*)(unsigned char**, long*, void*), void (*)(void const*, long, void*), void (*)(void*), bool (*)(unsigned char*, long), _Dart_Handle* (*)(), bool, Dart_CodeObserver*)+0x74
  pc 0x0000000105078f0c fp 0x000000016b77a4c0 Dart_Initialize+0x68
  pc 0x0000000104689600 fp 0x000000016b77a660 dart::bin::main(int, char**)+0x650
  pc 0x00000001a0b21430 fp 0x000000016b77a680 start+0x4
-- End of DumpStackTrace

[4619/5246] ACTION //third_party/dart/utils/kernel-service:kernel_service_dill(//build/toolchain/mac:clang_arm64)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
zsh: exit 1     ninja -C out/host_debug_unopt
```

Just before the above, I run the following.
(This is after preparing the engine in the environment at hand in the way described in this document.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Setting-up-the-Engine-development-environment)

```
~/development/engine/src# ./flutter/tools/gn --unoptimized
GOMA usage was specified but can't be found, falling back to local builds. Set the GOMA_DIR environment variable to fix GOMA.
Using prebuilt Dart SDK binary. If you are editing Dart sources and wish to compile the Dart SDK, set `--no-prebuilt-dart-sdk`.
Generating GN files in: out/host_debug_unopt
Generating Xcode projects took 113ms
Generating compile_commands took 26ms
Done. Made 585 targets from 221 files in 2943ms
```